# Customizing bibliography format with amsrefs

Tags: bibliographies, amsrefs

I often use `amsrefs` for my bibliographies, and get the entries directly from MathSciNet.  However, this often includes information I don't want to appear in my bibliography, such as MR numbers and DOI's, that amsrefs seems to print by default.

**Question:** Is there a simple way of telling `amsrefs` not to print certain data in the reference items?  (besides commenting out/deleting said data from each entry)

Looking at the documentation, I suspect this is possible with the `BibSpec` command, though I don't quite know how.  But even if one can do this with `BibSpec` I think one would need to do a `BibSpec` for each type of entry (`article`, `book`, etc), so if there's a "universal" way to do this, I would prefer that.

Comment: not tested: `\renewcommand{\MR}[1]{} \renewcommand{\PrintDOI}[1]{}` this is rather a sledgehammer, but if you want to get rid of them entirely, it should have the desired effect.